# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty with dynamic html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to integrate some ruby with some pre-written html markup.

Everything is working fine (routes, models etc) I can post data to the database with a regular form. However, I am trying to make a pre-written form dynamic.

I am getting an ArgumentError on the very first line:

`First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

```
<%= form_for @user_leads, url:  user_leads_path(@user_leads), html: {class: 'col-12'}, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
```

I've been trying to implement Ruby into this for a while now any help would be great

user_leads_controller.rb

```
class UserLeadsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user_lead = UserLead.all
  end

  def new
    @user_lead = UserLead.new

    @lead_reasons = LeadReason.all.map{ |r| [r.name, r.id] }
    @lead_sources = LeadSource.all.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id] }
  end

  def create
    @user_lead = UserLead.new(user_lead_params)
    @user_lead.lead_reason_id = params[:lead_reason_id]
    @user_lead.lead_source_id = params[:lead_source_id]

    @user_lead.save

    redirect_to user_leads_path
  end

  private

  def user_lead_params
    params.require(:user_lead).permit(:name, :businessname, :phone, :email, :amount)
  end
end
```

Erro here in view partial file: 'First argument cannot be nil or empty'

```
<%= form_for @user_lead, url: user_leads_path, html: {class: 'col-12'}, remote: true do |f| %>
        <div class="col-12 px-0 text-center">
          <h4 class="fl-color-navy">Some heading here</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 progress-container-center">
          <div class="col-12 progress-bar-block">
            <div class="progress-bar">
              <ol class="progress-steps">
                <li class="progress-step step1 current-step" style="width: 0%;"> <span class="count highlight-index"></span></li>
                <li class="progress-step step2 current-step" style="width: 100%;"> <span class="count"></span></li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> ....
```

Comment: `@user_leads` is nil. Can you update the question with the related controller code?

Comment: In which view page you have that form? Also are you trying to create a new `user_lead` or edit an existing `user_lead`?

Comment: `views/user_leads/new.html.erb` that page. I'm trying to create a new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

The problem is `@user_leads` is **nil** because its not defined. It should be `@user_lead` as per your code.

And as you are creating a new `user_lead`, the `url` should be just `user_leads_path` instead of `user_leads_path(@user_leads)`

```
<%= form_for @user_lead, url:  user_leads_path, html: {class: 'col-12'}, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
```

or just

```
<%= form_for @user_lead, html: {class: 'col-12'}, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
```

It can further shortened to below

```
<%= form_for @user_lead, html: {class: 'col-12'}, remote: true do |f| %>
```

as forms by default sends a `POST` request